# how to stream a console to the network

Tags: console, streaming

I have a Linux server running and I would like to stream the first four consoles (TTY1,TTY2,TTY3,TTY4) where I have different tails with with my log-files to the network so I can receive the stream in the way I receive a webcam in my network.

The reason is that my NVR (Network Video Recorder) Device can split the screen in 4 and display 4 log-files or even 16 log files in the same time.

The NVR supports the following protocols : N1 and ONVIF

I found different solutions to stream a media file, bit none for streaming the console.

Comment: What protocols does the NVR accept?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I remember 2 of them : N1 and ONVIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a video of TTY1 and pipe it to ffplay (you could do something else with it)

```
#!/bin/bash

(while sleep 1
do
    screendump 1 | anytopnm | pnmtojpeg
done) | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1 -c:v mjpeg -i - -c:v copy -f matroska - | ffplay -
```

You can also check when LOGFILE changes. Each time that happens it will get the last 25 files, convert them to an image and feed it to `ffmpeg`, that creates a matroska video file and writes it to `stdout`, where `ffplay` picks it up and plays it.

I left all the pipes so that you can decide where to insert the solutions you already had for media files.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/tmp/filename    

(while inotifywait -q -e modify $LOGFILE >/dev/null; do
    tail -25 $LOGFILE | anytopnm | pnmtojpeg
done) | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1/8 -c:v mjpeg -i - -c:v copy -f matroska - | ffplay -
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think you're working too hard.  Try looking at something like `tmux` which can do the console multiplexing, as well as allowing multiple connections to the console it creates.  You can also split the "screens" into multiple consoles, and switch between them.

[image: tmux example]

This is something that can easily be re-connected to from as many consoles as you have access to, as well as detaching from the tmux session, without killing any processes.

Comment: thank you very much for the idea, I didn't knew it. But Eduardo answer is the answer to my question.